# Create a list of time sequences from dates between 2 vectors

Tags: r, datetime

I'm new to loops.  I would like to do the following, but for an entire vector:

```
library(timedate)
timeSequence("2014-05-09 10:48:00", "2014-05-11 19:39:00", by = "min")
```

Here is a sample:

```
Dates <- data.frame(Start = c("2014-05-09 10:48:00",
                             "2014-05-11 19:39:00",
                             "2014-10-09 08:52:00",
                             "2014-10-29 10:48:59",
                             "2014-11-13 03:08:00"),
                       End = c("2014-05-11 19:39:00",
                              "2014-05-12 07:05:00",
                              "2014-10-29 10:48:59",
                              "2014-11-13 03:08:00",
                              "2014-11-13 08:41:59"))
```

I started with:

```
timeSequence(Dates$Start, Dates$End, by = "min)
```

But gets the error `'from' must be of length 1`...

So I've tried different iterations of `for` loops, with no success:

```
for (a in Dates$Start) {
  for (b in Dates$End) {
    Date_List <- timeSequence(a, b, by = "min")
  }
}
```

Here I get `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`.  I'd like to have a list where each item has the full sequence between dates in the vectors.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply`

```
library(timeDate)

mapply(timeSequence, from = Dates$Start, to = Dates$End, by = "min", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the looping method you can try the following.

```
require(timeDate)
Dates <- data.frame(Start = c("2014-05-09 10:48:00",
                          "2014-05-11 19:39:00",
                          "2014-10-09 08:52:00",
                          "2014-10-29 10:48:59",
                          "2014-11-13 03:08:00"),
                    End = c("2014-05-11 19:39:00",
                        "2014-05-12 07:05:00",
                        "2014-10-29 10:48:59",
                        "2014-11-13 03:08:00",
                        "2014-11-13 08:41:59"))
Dates$Start = as.POSIXct(Dates$Start,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Dates$End = as.POSIXct(Dates$End,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Date_List=NULL
for (a in 1:nrow(Dates)) {
  datetime <- timeSequence(Dates$Start[a],Dates$End[a], by = "mins")
  datetime <- datetime[isBizday(datetime, holidayNYSE())]
  Date_List[[a]] <- datetime@Data
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used `timesequence` as I'm also trying to use business days only for the sequence.  Using your `for` loop again, how would I get the same `Date_List` sequences implementing a holiday calendar from the `timedate` package?  I tried something like `for (b in 1:Date_List) {Date_List[[b]] <- isBizday(Date_List[[b]], holidayNYSE)}`.  No dice.  Same problem, I can do this for a single subset sequence and get the correct output, but not for all of them at once.  Thank you!

Comment: I updated the code to use the timeDate package. Hopefully this will work for your purposes